# how to add child window controls to CWindowImpl

Tags: atl

How do I add simple child window controls (e.g. a button) to a CWindowImpl?

I've looked at CWindowImpl and CDialogImpl. With CDialogImpl, it appears that you just create a dialog template resource and use it, very simple. I would like to do something similar with CWindowImpl, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do it. Must I add the controls manually and position them programmatically?

Some context on what I'm trying to do: I'm trying to create a plug-in for foobar2000, a Windows audio player. I would like to create a "UI element" plugin, and in the sample code that I've looked at, a "UI element" is created via CWindowImpl. How do I add buttons to this CWindowImpl? I've tried using a CDialogImpl instead, but this gives me a "pop-up" dialog, which is not what I'm looking for.

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With any window, including CDialogImpl, you can add child controls by creating a new window of control class and specifying your parent window handle as a parent for new control. Additionally, [SetParent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633541%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is here to re-parent any window.